# IOS: GLPaint erase an imageview

Tags: ios, xcode, opengl-es, brush

I'm usin GLPaint to paint inside an UIView, but not I want to using an erasing brush.
I know that the code to have a erase brush is:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ZERO);
glColor4f(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
```

but if I put in my UIView an imageView I want to delete it also...is it possible?

Comment: What are you trying to do? I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish from your question. Are you trying to erase part of an image? If so, you need to upload the image to a texture and go from there. Can you give some more details of what you're attempting to do?

Comment: sure...I'm using PaintingView (a class of GLPaint) in a UIView, and this UIView is inside a View controller; then I want so to set a backgroud inside in UIView that I can erase with a brush and when I erase this backgroud it should show me an image that is inside viewcontroller...is it clare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possible ways to do this, but here's what I would try first. Inside your `PaintingView`, draw a textured quad with the image textured onto it. Then draw a textured quad over that with your paint strokes on it. Set the blending mode to the normal over mode (`glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);`). Then wherever the source alpha is 0, you'll see the textured quad with the image through it.